# React Datepicker - inline style doesn't work

Tags: css, reactjs, datepicker, onblur, inline-styles

I'm triggering onBlur javascript function to turn the border of inputs red if the entry is invalid.

This is working fine except for Datepicker.

I can style its border using classname but I need to use inline style to make it change depending on what is input. How can I do this?

My code:

```
state= {
    borderColors:{
        startDetails: 'none',
    }
}

borderColor = (e, field) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let borderColors = this.state.borderColors
    e.target.value === '' ? borderColors[field] = 'tomato' : borderColors[field] = '#00988f'
    this.setState({borderColors})
}



  <DatePicker
     className="datePicker"
     timeIntervals={15}
     selected={values.startDetails}
     onBlur = {event => this.borderColor(event, 'startDetails')}
     onChange={(event) => this.props.changeField(event, "startDetails")}
     showTimeSelect
     dateFormat="d MMM yyyy HH:mm"
     required
     placeholderText={'Date & Time Event Starts'}
     style={{borderColor: this.state.borderColors.startDetails}}
     />
```

Comment: please share a link of this component doc

Comment: try string literals `style={{borderColor: ${\`this.state.borderColors.startDetails\`}}}`

Comment: String literals aren't working unfortunately.

Comment: The component is here: https://github.com/colmfah/Tickets-v2-Frontend/blob/master/src/Components/CreateEventComponents/EventDetails.js

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by deleting the border around datePicker by setting its width to zero in css file.

Then I wrapped datePicker in a div, gave it a border and set an inline style in the div to set the border color according to the value in state that is set by the function